# Create copy of the Image when Checked - Jquery

Tags: jquery, image, checkbox, clone

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RbJeL/)

I have multiple images with checkboxes each.. When i check, the respective images should **create copy** to the bottom-wrap Div. And when i uncheck it should not create a copy..
How to achieve this.?

Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="top-wrap">
    <img src="sampleImage.jpg">
    <input type="checkbox">
</div>

<div class="bottom-wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: That's more of an HTMLFiddle, no? Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: ya sorry.. This one i have tried >> http://jsfiddle.net/RbJeL/2/

Comment: but i need respective image of that particular checkbox should be cloned..

Answer (score 0):

I'd add data- attribute to target the corresponding image FYI.

Working fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/RbJeL/7/

```
<div class="top-wrap">
    <img data-i="1" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png">
        <input type="checkbox" data-t="1">
            <img data-i="2" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png">
        <input type="checkbox" data-t="2">
            <img data-i="3" src="https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/mdn-logo-sm.png">
        <input type="checkbox" data-t="3">
</div>

<script>
   $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click", function(){
        if( $(this).is(":checked") ) 
            $("img[data-i="+$(this).attr("data-t")+"]").appendTo(".bottom-wrap")
        else
            $("img[data-i="+$(this).attr("data-t")+"]").appendTo(".top-wrap")            
   });
 </script>


 <div class="bottom-wrap">
     <span>Selected Images</span> 
 </div>
```

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't contain any JavaScript.

Comment: I tried this.. But i have multiple pairs of images and checkboxes.. I cant give data-i and data-t for each of the pairs.. how do i generalize it?

Comment: @user3378393 you can write a loop that will automatically append the the attribute at document load. I.e. each input, find prev() and append counter value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below:

```
$(function() {
    var imageId = 0;
    $('.top-wrap input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        var el = $(this);

        if (el.is(':checked')) {
            $('.bottom-wrap').append(el.prev('img').clone().attr('id', 'img-' + imageId));
            el.data('cloneId', 'img-' + imageId);
            imageId++;
        } else {
            $('.bottom-wrap #' + el.data('cloneId')).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/RbJeL/9/)**

Hide / Show Method

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-wrap input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        var clone = $('.bottom-wrap #img-' + el.index());
        if (el.is(':checked')) {
            if (clone.length) {
                clone.show();
            } else {
            $('.bottom-wrap').append(el.prev('img').clone().attr('id', 'img-' + el.index()));
            }
        } else {
            clone.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo Link (Hide/Show)](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/RbJeL/11/)**

Comment: @Reigel Updated now using `prev` instead of `next`, as `image` is before `checkbox`

Comment: adding/removing elements is not a good practice I think... I updated your code, to check if the image is there then just show/hide it. only create image if not cloned yet http://jsfiddle.net/V3gZd/1/